# Leaks in CPTColor & CPTColorSpace

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have noticed 2 small leaks related to CPTColor and CPTColorSpace when testing with the leaks instrument on the device. I only use the CPTColor class methods and do not retain any of the CPTColor objects returned. Is this a leak in the Core Plot framework?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you have the code which shows the CPTColor and CPTColorSpace which Instruments tags as leaking? It's possible this is a framework issue, but more details are needed to determine this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPTColor creates static instances of the predefined color objects (blackColor, redColor, greenColor, etc.) for performance. Similarly, `+[CPTColorSpace genericRGBSpace]` creates a static color space instance. These static objects are never released and therefore get reported as leaks.